# how to get the return of an ajax request that I didn't send

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a request that is being made on the site, but I didn't make this request, but I need to get the result of it. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use global listener. Here is example from the `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js` where the customer data is updated when customer changes something on the frontend:

```
/**
 * Events listener
 */
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
    customerData.onAjaxComplete(xhr.responseJSON, settings); // Write your code here
});
```

This way you can get any response to any ajax call, but you should determine if it's target request or not.